# Проблема в обработке данных. Связанные списки, где элементом является массив

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, структуры-данных, обработка-данных

Задача стоит следующим образом:
Вычислить фрактальную размерность объекта, который расположен в многомерном пространстве. Для решения задачи применяется разбиение пространства на ячейки (гиперкубы)(иногда используют разбиение на окружности).

Идея решения:

- разбивая пространство на ячейки по каждой координате задаются числа;
  например, если пространство разбито на две части, а размерность равна 5, тогда каждая ячейка это массив:

  a[5] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}

Если ячеек больше, то числа (1, 0) принимают другие значения (2, 3, ...).

Необходимо считать количество ячеек в которые попадает объект.

Была предринята попытка использовать сортировку методом бинарного дерева:

```
    struct tnode
{
    int field[N];           // N - размерность
    struct tnode *left;  
    struct tnode *right; 
};
```

tnode - по сути ячейка. 
далее определенным образом происходит сортировка:

```
struct tnode * addnode(int *x, tnode *tree) {

    if (tree == NULL)     // Если дерева нет, то формируем корень
    {
        Bool = true;
        tree = new tnode; //память под узел
        for (int i = 0; i < el; i++)
        {
            tree->field[i] = x[i];  
        }
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL; //ветви инициализируем пустотой

    }

        else if (!equal(tree -> field, tree -> field + el, x))
        for (int i = 0; i < el; i++)
        {

            if (x[i] < tree-> field[i])   //Если элемент x меньше корневого, уходим влево
            {
                tree->left = addnode(x, tree->left); //Рекурсивно добавляем элемент
                break;
            }
            else if (x[i] > tree-> field[i]) 
            {
                tree -> right = addnode(x, tree->right); //Рекурсивно добавляем элемент
                break;
            }
        }
    return(tree);
}
```

Суть: если представить элементы массива, как число: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]: 12345, b = [2,1,3,1,2]: 21312 - по такому правилу b > a.

Неудовлетворяет сокрость выполнения кода.
Возможно необходимо использовать обычные массивы, лучше динамические, но тогда возникает проблемма сортировки. Использование структуры обусловлено тем, что элементом связанного списка является массив. 
Возможно ли ускорить работу кода (используя другие методы сортировки или типы данных)?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85257/discussion-on-question-by-pug-mech------).